# Java UDP packet read failing

Tags: java, udp

I am trying to send packets from one host to another peer host using java UDP protocol.

The one host sends data, while the other reads it. The corresponding read however keeps blocking, thus receiving no data. I can see the sender packets going to the right destination using wireshark, but the receiver just wont pick it up. The read operation keeps blocking indefinitely.

Please help.
Code for cient:

```
//CLIENT CLASS
//Sections ommited....
DatagramSocket so = new DatagramSocket(port);
    protected void send(byte[] buffer,int packetsize){  
        DatagramPacket p;
        try {
            myClient.notifyInform("Sending data to "+inetaddress+" on"+port+"\n");
            p=new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,InetAddress.getByName(inetaddress),port);
            writeLock.lock();
            try{
                so.send(p);
            }finally{
                writeLock.unlock();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            myClient.perror("Could not connect to peer:"+e.getMessage()+"\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            myClient.perror("IOException while sending to peer.\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected DatagramPacket read(){
        byte[] buf=new byte[bufsize];
        DatagramPacket p=new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);//TODO check these values, what should buffer be? just made it psize*10 for now
        readLock.lock();
        try{                
            myClient.notifyInform("receiving data\n");
            so.receive(p);
            this.myclient.notifyInform(String.valueOf(p.getData().length)+"\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            myClient.perror("IOException while reading from peer.\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            readLock.unlock();
        }
        return p;
    }

    protected void beginRead() {
        while(active) {

            System.out.println("########################");
            byte[] data=this.read().getData();
            myClient.notifyInform("Receiving data\n");
        }

    }
    protected void beginSend(){
        forkWork(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                byte[] sendBuffer=new byte[bufsize];
                int cnt;
                while(callActive){
                    try{
                        sourceLock.lock();
                        cnt=dataSource.read(sendBuffer, 0, bufsize);
                    }finally{
                        sourceLock.unlock();
                    }
                    if (cnt >0) {
                        send(sendBuffer, packetsize);
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    }
```

UPDATE:I made a mistake that I finally tracked down. After binding the port, and fixing that error, it now works.

Comment: could the a firewall block it? do you use anything special like multicast addresses?

Comment: No, I have all firewalls turned off, and not using multicast.

Comment: Two easy possibilities: something else has already bound that port, or you are on a Unix/Linux platform and attempting to bind a port number less than 1024 without being root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the port that the datagram socket is listening on like this:

```
 this.so = new DatagramSocket(SOME_NUMBER_HERE);
```

and make sure you send it to the same port number in the `send()` method

Answer (score 1):

Is your receiving DatagramSocket listening at the IP:port the sender is sending to?

Comment: DatagramSocket does not specify that.It only reads what is sent to it? This is my code for socket init : this.so = new DatagramSocket();

Comment: @Vort3x, it won't hear anything if its not listening to any IP & port.

Comment: @Vort3x On the contrary. The Javadoc specifically says that `new DatagramSocket()` 'binds it to any available port'. So unless you are coincidentally sending to exactly that port, it won't receive those transmissions. That's the meaning of binding, and port numbers. So don't do that. Try `new DatagramSocket(port)`; where `port` is the same as you are sending to.

Comment: @EJP THanks, I have misread the doc. I have now bound the port, and it works on localhost. But it wont work across the network, give me a java.net.BindException.

Comment: @Vort3x misread or not read? you were pretty dogmatic. Anyway BindException has nothing to do with 'across the network', it just means something else is already listening at that port.

Comment: @EJP I did read the javadocs, but I confess I was in a hurry and missed some of the details. Thanks for the help.